# React native typescript cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm in the process of converting our react-native project from js to typescript. However, for the old modules that we're importing, I'm getting the error of

```
Cannot find module 'numeral'
```

The 'numeral' module is clearly in the `/node_modules` directory though

Answer (score 0):

It turns out for node modules used by typescript file, we can just do `yarn add @types/numeral --dev` to add the node module in the `node_modules/@types` folder and the issue is resolved

Comment: do you know a proper way to do it automatically? like a script, or a proper package that fixes this issue?